# Use common files across various domains

Tags: php, include, subdomain

I've got a site with dozens of sub directories. Each sub directory represents a different client:

```
client1.mydomain.com 
client1.mydomain.com 
...
```

> If you do not want to read all of the details, you may skip to the
>   quote towards the bottom of the question

I don't want to have to keep to copy of my site's files for each new sub directory so instead I'd rather have each sub directory call upon the files in the root directory when they need to be used.

Is there a best practice for doing something like this? I understand I can use `PHP's` `include` or `require` to load in scripts from the root directory, but then how do I handle re-directions, or the issue of bringing a user to the correct file depending on where he's coming from?

Should I keep a copy of all of the site's files in each sub directory and the contents of each "copy" will be a simple `require_once` ? Otherwise, what if a user at client1.mydomain.com clicks on the `About us` link, how can I separte that action from a user of client 2 clicking on the same link and making sure they end up in different places (client1.mydomain.com/about-us and client2.mydomain.com/about-us, respectively)?

> I'm really just looking for a best practice of implementing a site
>   with many sub domains, which all use a common set of files from the
>   root directory.

Thank you.

Comment: really depends on the sites, how they work etc, no simple answer to this.

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for the response. Is there some more information I could provide that would make for an easier answer?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want them to share a set of libraries or something similar? Having a directory where you could put these shared files and include that directory in the include path for all the sub-domains would work.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the answer. Yes, I was thinking of having all of the shared files stored in the root directory and each sub domain would then use these shared files through inclusion ( `include ../some_file.php` ). However, one of these files, for example, will be the `header.php` file which will generate all of the opening HTML - navigation, body, etc. - So what will happen when a user clicks on the "About us" tab from one of the subdomains? How can I ensure that when client 1 clicks on "About us" it directs him to "client1.mysite.com/about-us"? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If security is not an issue here, the answer is pretty simple. Just place the shared files and include them in your site-specific php files. To generate the correct links, you can choose to use either one of the following methods

1. Relative links. Like href="/about".
2. Build a absolute link in your shared php.
3. Pass necessary information to the shared php through some global variable.

All simple to implement.

Comment: What kind of security ramifications could exist?

Comment: For example, in a trivial setup of lamp serving multiple sites, if the scripts of one site are buggy and got hacked, all other sites become vulnerable because they are all run as the same user. So for security enhanced websites, you might wanna keep them virtually/physically separated or sandboxed.